# I want to add active class with nav-link in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to add an active class with the .nav-link

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar-nav">
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a asp-area="DemoArea" class="nav-link" asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Index">Dashboard</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems to be more of a JavaScript question, but you tagged .NET Core, can you please clarify?

Comment: I want to manage using viewbag and TagHelpers parameter in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Did you want to dynamic add `.nav-link` class by ViewBag value?

Comment: <a asp-area="DemoArea" class="nav-link @(ViewBag.Class==true?"active":"")" asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Index">Dashboard</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo for dynamic add class by ViewBag value:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar-nav">
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a asp-area="DemoArea" class="@(ViewBag.Class==true?"nav-link":"")" asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Index">Dashboard</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Backend:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.Class = true;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to do this, Not the best answer but it works too. And you can add menu levels as you want... see the code below:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           var currentUrl = document.location.pathname;

            var elementLevelZero = $('.nav-main a[href="' + currentUrl + '"]');
            $(elementLevelZero).addClass('active');

            var elementLevelZeroList = $(elementLevelZero).closest('ul');

            var elementLevelOne = $(elementLevelZeroList).prev("a");
            $(elementLevelOne).addClass('active');

            var elementLevelOneList = $($(elementLevelOne).parent()).closest('ul');

            var elementLevelTwo = $(elementLevelOneList).prev("a");
            $(elementLevelTwo).addClass('active'); 

            var elementLevelTwoList = $($(elementLevelTwo).parent()).closest('ul');

            var elementLevelThree = $(elementLevelTwoList).prev("a");
            $(elementLevelThree).addClass('active'); 
        });
    </script>
```

You can use .each function to loop on each parent item in your list.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the static class MenuStateHelper and static method MakeActiveClass along with that I have passed controller name and action method name when both passed values and RouteData value match then it will return active class else it will be null.

```
public static class MenuStateHelper
{
    public static string MakeActiveClass(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string controller, string action)
    {
        try
        {
            string result = "active";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(urlHelper.ActionContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"])))
            {
                string areaName = urlHelper.ActionContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();
            }

            if (urlHelper.ActionContext.RouteData.Values != null)
            {
                string controllerName = urlHelper.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
                string methodName = urlHelper.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName)) return null;
                if (controllerName.Equals(controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (methodName != null && methodName.Equals(action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

And I have called **MakeActiveClass** method on Anchor Tag Helper

```
<a asp-area="@menu.Area" asp-controller="@menu.ControllerName" asp-action="@menu.ActionMethod" class="nav-link @Url.MakeActiveClass(menu.ControllerName, menu.ActionMethod)">
    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
    <p>
        @menu.MenuName
    </p>
  </a>
```